# Login with Microsoft and twitter

Tags: angular

I've integrated social logins (Google and Facebook) through ng4-social-login and now finding a way to integrate microsoft based accounts.
And also finding with twitter

Answer (score 0):

Use MSAL for Microsoft accounts.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular

Comment: can i implement like google auth?  like this..!  import {AuthService, SocialUser, GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider, LinkedinLoginProvider} from 'ng4-social-login'; googlelogin(){
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then((userData)=>{
      this.user =userData;
    });
  }

Comment: I don't think so as MSAL is not implemented in the ng4-social-login library you're using. You will have to write your own service to handle the login.